# What is the underlying mechanism of C compiler when comapring an char(signed) to an unsigned char?

Tags: c, integer, char

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c = -65;
    unsigned char uc = 191, uc2 = c;
    printf("%d %d", uc == c, uc2);
}
```

expecting 1, because uc is '10111111' and c is '10111111',
actual result is 0

Comment: Are you sure that `char` is signed on your target and with your compiler? Unlike other integer types, `char` can be either signed or unsigned, but it's up to the compiler to decide.

Comment: Basically it gets converted into `int` before the comparison. Only as an non lvalue in that expression (aka the object type is not changed). But yeah you can read like the C standard on this. (3.2 Conversions - fipspub160)

Comment: @MIke I'm laughing - this won't work though. But maybe I'm wrong at some points anywho - in any case its worth reading nonetheless.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/djWoTc6G6 <- comparison is `cmp     ecx, eax`, the difference is between `movzx   ecx, BYTE PTR [rbp-2]` (zx = zero extend) and `movsx   eax, BYTE PTR [rbp-1]` (sx = sign extend)